# Get Window Instance/Object From Handle (hWnd)

Tags: vba, winapi

Working in VB/VBA, I have a window handle and I need to convert it to a window object/instance which I can use to access the window object's properties.

AccessibleObjectFromWindow has not proven useful.

How do I do this?

### Update

Below is additional detail.

I am working with a window created using mshta.exe and configured with some scripts:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%systemroot%\syswow64\mshta.exe about:""<head><script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);document.title='" & x86WindowSignature & "'</script><hta:application showintaskbar=no /><object id='shell' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shell.putproperty('" & x86WindowSignature & "',document.parentWindow);</script></head>""", 0, False

        For Each Window In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Getx86Window = Window.GetProperty(x86WindowSignature)
            Error = Err.Number
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Error = 0 Then Exit For
            Pause 0.01, True
        Next Window

' Configure the window environment - global object variables are defined, one for each scripting object - they are instantiated by calling the Initialize routine
Getx86Window.execScript "var VBScript, JScript;"
Getx86Window.execScript "Sub Initialize() : Set VBScript = CreateObject(""MSScriptControl.ScriptControl"") : VBScript.Language = ""VBScript"" : Set JScript = CreateObject(""MSScriptControl.ScriptControl"") : JScript.Language = ""JScript"" End Sub", "VBScript"

' Initialize the window environment
Getx86Window.Initialize
```

x86WindowSignature is a function that returns a unique string or key.

I'm going through this process because Microsoft doesn't provide 64-bit versions of the VBScript and JScript engines and this process allows me to create 32-bit versions and use them from a 64-bit world.

To reuse this scripting container I need to look at the existing windows and query one of the properties I created:

```
Set Getx86Window = Window.GetProperty(x86WindowSignature)
```

Normally I use this logic to find the window of interest:

```
' Look for an existing window
For Each Window In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Getx86Window = Window.GetProperty(x86WindowSignature)
    Error = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Error = 0 Then Exit Function
Next Window
```

But, if the application crashes or otherwise fails to close the scripting window, it remains open but is not listed with CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows.

But I can find it using FindWindow:

```
WindowHandle = API_FindWindow("HTML Application Host Window Class", x86WindowSignature)
```

I'm stuck trying to convert the window handle to a VB/VBA "Window" object variable.

I tried a simple copy memory from the handle variable to the object variable but that failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077542/get-object-from-windows-handle/1077555#1077555

Comment: What properties do you want?

Comment: Here's the brutal truth: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Instead of asking about the problem you are trying to solve, you asked about your proposed solution. The answer to the question you should have asked is [GetProp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getpropw). You don't need a wrapper object for that.

Comment: @IInspectable Can you actually use `GetProp` to return `IHtmlWindow2` from a hwnd?

Comment: @gse: `GetProp` returns the data handle associated with a particular key. The handle can be set using [SetProp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setpropw): *"The data handle can identify **any value** useful to the application."* A COM interface pointer is a suitable value.

Comment: @IInspectable So you are saying that, upon receiving the pointer to the shell window object, the OP should store that same pointer against that window's hwnd using `SetProp`, so that in the event of a crash, they could retrieve the pointer from the hwnd with `GetProp`?

Comment: GetProp returns another handle. I need to convert a handle to a Window object usable in VB/VBA. Let me be clear: I need to convert a Window handle to a Window object in VB/VBA, or in the brutal reality of XY problem land, I need to find the window that I created in another process given its title and class, and I need to translate that window reference into an object with which I can call properties such as: Set Window = Window.GetProperty(“…”), Set JScriptObject = ScriptWindow.JScript, and Set VBScriptObject = ScriptWindow.VBScript. This is VBA, not C# or C++ or …

Comment: @gse: I linked to `SetProp` for the sole reason of explaining, what data associated with a key is. It's publicly accessible (as long as you know the key), but it's interpretation is generally not documented. I wasn't suggesting that *you* call `SetProp`, and I certainly wasn't recommending to write code with the expectation, that it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I made an incorrect observation in my initial work. I thought that I was not getting all the windows returned to me that I had created. That is not true. This line:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
```

always returns all the windows that were created by Shell.Application. So I had at my disposal all the windows my application had created in the past.

When I posed my question, I thought that I could only get those "lost" window objects by using lower level Windows SDK calls and then somehow convert those hWnds into Shell.Application window object references. I never did figure out how to do that or if it is even possible but that need is no longer required.

Comment: Hey Kevin. It looks like the commentary you made became out of date, as the question was reopened - hopefully that goes some way to showing that good questions will survive here. However I should note that we discourage/remove meta-commentary from question and answer posts - we want them focussed entirely on the problem and not on the process of getting help.

Comment: If you'd like to talk to the community audience about how things could be improved, we encourage [Meta questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: However, it is worth noting that 99% of people's complaints are not new. My feedback on your feedback so far is that questions are closed when they do not meet the posting standards (based on three democratic votes) and they are opened again if the post is improved or three democratic votes can be found that disagree with the initial assessment.

Comment: Seasoned users here do understand that voting/editing can feel unusual ("It's _my_ post, why are people amending it!") but it is not brutal at all - it is improvement. We think of ourselves rather closer to Wikipedia than Experts Exchange. The best approach if you experience some frustration is just to see the interactions as part of the process, keep a positive view of people's volunteering, and try not to retaliate as much as humanly possible. Good questions will be reopened and upvoted in the end. Good luck!